# Using CSS Theme from two or more frameworks

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint, jquery-easyui

I work with a JS framework than heavily leverages jEasyUI.
We have a need in various projects to combine using jEasyUI with Twitter Bootstrap theme. Another project wants to put EasyUI widgets inside Sharepoint.

This problem is not specific to just jEasyUI but rather combining "themes" from two or more frameworks.

In Sharepoint we found that both have a concept of "Tabs" therefore depending which stylesheet we included first, it screwed up the Tabs of the other product. With Bootstrap, because it styles most basic HTML elements, it interferes with how widgets are rendered from other UI frameworks as it can over-ride styles of basic elements.

I'm not really sure what the solution is. Or I'm wondering what is the best/easiest way to combine both. 
It feels like I need to combine the theme from two frameworks then manually go back and fix indvidual elements to they "work together".

Has anyone faced this challenge before and is there a good or faster process for doing this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap you can [customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/) your download to specific components. If you only choose the ones you need, there will be minimal style collisions.